# Animate Line under one button to another

Tags: swift

In Swift, I was trying to replicate the animated underline from this App. When a user taps "local" or "world", the underline bar slides across the screen and positions under the button selected.

How is the animation done? Is the bar an imageview that moves?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask:

> How is the animation done? Is the bar an imageview that moves?

More than likely it's just a `UIView` whose background color is that light blue, and whose frame (or whose constraints that define the frame) are changed within a `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` block.

---

For example, in Objective-C, you might have these properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *underlineView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *underlineConstraints;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
```

and this code:

```
- (void)addUnderline {
    UIView *underlineView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    underlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    underlineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:underlineView];
    self.underlineView = underlineView;

    [self updateConstraintsForUnderlineView:underlineView underButton:self.button1];
}

- (IBAction)didTapButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self updateConstraintsForUnderlineView:self.underlineView underButton:sender];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)updateConstraintsForUnderlineView:(UIView *)underlineView underButton:(UIButton *)button {
    if (self.underlineConstraints) {
        [self.view removeConstraints:self.underlineConstraints];
    }

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(underlineView, button);
    self.underlineConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-[underlineView(5)]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:self.underlineConstraints];
}
```

Or in Swift:

```
weak var underlineView: UIView!
var underlineConstraints: [AnyObject]!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

func addUnderline() {
    let underlineView = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    underlineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    view.addSubview(underlineView)
    self.underlineView = underlineView

    updateConstraintsForUnderlineView(underlineView, underButton:button1)
}

@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
    updateConstraintsForUnderlineView(underlineView, underButton:sender)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}

func updateConstraintsForUnderlineView(underlineView: UIView, underButton button: UIButton) {
    if underlineConstraints != nil {
        view.removeConstraints(underlineConstraints)
    }

    let views = ["underlineView": underlineView, "button": button]
    underlineConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[button]-[underlineView(5)]", options: .AlignAllLeading | .AlignAllTrailing, metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(underlineConstraints)
}
```

Comment: So it's a single UIView. Would it work to set constraints equal to the space blow Button1, then change the constraints to equal the space below Button2 and add animateWithDuration? Are there different animation effects or is it likely using the default effect?

Comment: The standard animation looks fine IMHO, but I might want to use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`, so it snaps away from the one it's leaving, but eases into the destination. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: @Rob would you mind doing a swift version of this? I found this very useful but some parts I'm not sure of the swift equivalent. ie: `self.underlineView = underlineView;` brings up an error. And not sure how to convert this `- (void)updateConstraintsForUnderlineView:(UIView *)underlineView underButton:(UIButton *)button {` Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @Emma It is literally a line-for-line conversion, absolutely nothing special happening here, but see revised answer. You undoubtedly just didn't have a property called `underlineView`, which I thought was easily inferred by the code sample, but added to make this explicit. Clearly, though, in your app, you'd use a better button name than `button1`. And, of course, you have to hook up your `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` references...